# Excel macro Hide and unhide row

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro that hides row where we have zero cells, but I want to add one more code that will unhide it too. Hide and unhide together.  The code is below:

```
    Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("U9:U149")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value = 0 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want the same code to toggle the rows between hidden / visible, then change it to:

```
Sub ToggleHideRows()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("U9:U149")
        If Not IsEmpty(c) And c.Value = 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = Not c.EntireRow.Hidden
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I've changed your variable name from `cell` to `c` - it's a bad idea to used 'special' words as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide rows with 0 and show rows without 0?

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("U9:U149")
        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = (c.Value = 0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```